# Retornar mensagem para usuario

Tags: php, laravel, validação, login

Gostaria que caso desse erro ao logar retornasse uma mensagem para o usuário

Na minha view **login.blade.php** está assim

```html
div class="login-form">
    <form action="{{ route('logar') }}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        {{--<h2 class="text-center">Log in</h2>--}}
        <div class="text-center">
            <img src="{{ URL('img/logo_poraque.png') }}" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="150">
        </div>

        <br />
        
        @if ($errors->has('msg'))
            <div style="text-align: center">
                <span class="help-block has-error" >
                      <strong>{{ $errors->first('msg') }}</strong>
                </span>
            </div>
        @endif
        
        <div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('login') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="required" name="login" value="{{ old('login') }}">
            @if ($errors->has('login'))
                <span class="help-block">
                  <strong>{{ $errors->first('login') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="form-group  has-feedback {{ $errors->has('senha') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required" name="senha">
            @if ($errors->has('senha'))
                <span class="help-block">
                  <strong>{{ $errors->first('senha') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log in</button>
        </div>
       <!-- <div class="clearfix">
            <label class="pull-left checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
            <a href="#" class="pull-right">Forgot Password?</a>
        </div>
        -->
    </form>
```

Na minha rota **web.php** está assim:

```
Route::post( '/logar', [ 'as' => 'logar', 'uses' => 'UsuarioController@logar' ] );
```

No meu **UsuarioController.php** está assim:

```html
public function logar(Request $request){
        $login = $request->input( 'login' );
        $senha = $request->input( 'senha' );
        
            $usuario = Usuario::where( [
                ['usua_login', $login]
            ])->first();

            
              $user = Usuario::where( [
                  ['usua_login', $login],
                  ['usua_senha', sha1( $senha )]
              ])->first();

              if( $user !== null ){

                  Session::put([
                      'login' =>  $login,
                      'id'    =>  $user->usua_id
                  ]);
                  return redirect()->route('telaPrincipal');
              }else{
                  $msg = array(
                      "msg" => "Login ou senha não são válidos"
                  ); 
                  return redirect()->back()->withErrors( $msg )->withInput();
              }
      }
```

Porém quando erro a senha, retorna para o login e não nenhuma mensagem

O que pode ser?

Se eu der o `print_r(  )` no controller ele mostra onde cai mas nao retorna com a mensagem na view.

Comment: Acho que pode ser no blade na forma que envia os erros tenta validar com @if($errors->any())

Comment: Só lembrando que o snippet do site NÃO funciona quando o código não é somente HTML/CSS/JS, então não há porque utilizá-lo em outras situações. Use, para esses casos, a ferramenta de trecho de código, `{}`.

Comment: @Panda mesmo assim , não voltou nada.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Na verdade estou usando no blade.php que é assim: `{{  }}`

Comment: Talvez não seja o tipo de resposta que te agradaria, mas já tentou usar o auth ?
Vai na raiz do projeto e cria com o artisan, "php artisan make:auth" ele vai criar o sistema básico completo de autenticação já com os erros tratados; depois vocês edita as views que ele cria em resources/views/auth e pronto já vai estar funcionando.

Comment: Pra escrever um código ao invés de string {!! !!};

Comment: Este código funcionava antes. Não entendo porque parou. Se pelo menos desse erro

Comment: Eu prefiro criar minha própria autenticação

Answer (score 2):

Caso queira enviar uma mensagem qualquer, pode usar **Session Flash Data**.

Por exemplo, antes do *return* do erro de login, coloca isso

```
$request->session()->flash('alert-danger', 'Login ou senha não são válidos.');
return redirect('/login');
```

Para recuperar, coloque em **login.blade.php** esse código abaixo que irá mostrar a mensagem com o texto inserido.

```
@foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $msg)
    @if(Session::has('alert-' . $msg))
        <div class="alert alert-{{ $msg }}" role="alert">
            {!! Session::get('alert-' . $msg) !!}
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Basicamente estamos fazendo um loop em alguns tipos de alertas do *bootstrap* (danger, warning, success enfo), e verificando se existe alguma sessão com dados, caso tenha mostra o alerta.

Para uma mensagem de sucesso poderia ser alguma coisa do gênero

```
$request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Dados alterados com sucesso.');
```

Gosto de colocar esse loop com a recuperação de alertas em uma página separada, por exemplo **parciais/mensagem-topo.blade.php**, e coloco um include dessa página em um cabeçalho do sistema ou páginas que possam mostrar um alerta.

```
@include('parciais.mensagem-topo')
```